# Ruby Regex matching help

Tags: ruby, regex, string, string-matching

This is just a general 'What is wrong with my regex that its not pulling out everything I expected' question.

Here's my string:

```
"Mon 0900-1600 1700-2000"
```

and I'd like to be able to pull out the times `"0900-1600"` and `"1700-2000"`.

This is my regexp `/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})/` and while it works great at finding the first occurrence of the time, it doesn't return a match to the second.  Could someone tell me why?

Here's my actual code snippet for the record:

```
str = "Mon 0900-1600 1700-2000"

/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})/.match(str)  #<MatchData "0900-1600">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`string#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) instead:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > str = "Mon 0900-1600 1700-2000"
 => "Mon 0900-1600 1700-2000" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > str.scan /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})/
 => [["0900-1600"], ["1700-2000"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use String#split?

```
asdf = "Mon 0900-1600 1700-2000"
asdf.split(' ')[1,2] #=> ["0900-1600", "1700-2000"]
```

Otherwise simplify and use:

```
asdf.scan(/\d+-\d+/) #=> ["0900-1600", "1700-2000"]
```

Comment: `split` is good when the substrings you want to throw out follow a simple pattern whereas `scan` is good when the substrings that you want to get follow a simple pattern. In this case, it is definetely the latter. I see no reason you should use split in this case.

Comment: @sawa, There is no "definitely". All we know about the problem is what the OP said. Based on the description both are adequate, however split is simpler.

Comment: Using `split` here requires two steps. You have to do `[1, 2]` to get rid of `"Mon"`. That is because the first substring that you want to throw out (`"Mon"`) and the separator `" "` are not homogeneous. Isn't that more complicated than doing it in one step as with `scan` in your second example?